# Cant pause audio playback in JS

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I´m working on another assignment for my Frontend course
and I have a function which play a sound if the user enable the function from settings in on the website.
When the user first open the website it stores isMusicEnable = false to localStorage and when the user presses enable music in settings it changes to true. I have gotten that to work. When the user enable music it starts to play but when the user press disable music it keeps playing. I have checked and the isMusicEnable changes to false in localStorage.

```
            var audio = new Audio('/sound/menyMusic.mp3');
           // audio.volume = this.getAudioVolume();
            if (this.isMusicOn() == true){
                audio.loop = true;
                audio.play();
            }
            else if(this.isMusicOn() == false){
                audio.pause();
                audio.currentTime = 0;
            }
        },
```

```
            let musicEnable = this.getItem('isMusicEnable');
            if (musicEnable == 'true'){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        },
```

I dont understand why it dosen´t work.

Comment: show your function which enables/disables music

Comment: With this project, I use Vue and have one button called enable-music which sets the value of isMusicEnable to true and one button called disable-music which sets the value to false. Then I call a function in a helper class that adds the value to localStorage.saveToStorage: function(){
            this.addItem('isSoundEnable', this.isSoundEnable);
            this.addItem('isTimerEnable', this.isTimerEnable);
            this.addItem('volume', this.volume);
            this.addItem('isMusicEnable', this.isMusicEnable);
        }

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your `this.isMusicOn()` function always returns `true`.

Regardless of the answer, your code is redundant. Any value is **always** interpreted either as true or as false. In addition, the argument of "if" is cast to a Boolean value. So, comparison with "*true*" does not make sense.
Therefore, the code can be simplified:

```
// audio.volume = this.getAudioVolume();
            if (this.isMusicOn()) {
                audio.loop = true;
                audio.play();
            }
            else {
                audio.pause();
                audio.currentTime = 0;
            }
```

Comment: I have checked the this.isMusicOn() function and it returns true when it should and false when It should.